# Create New Column with Unique Integer from Three Other Columns in ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table with many columns.

```
some_integer_1, some_integer_2, some_date, other
123             9               2019-01-01 "Some text"
123             9               2019-01-01 "Other text"
123             5               2019-02-01 "Hello"
56              3               2019-03-01 "World"
```

I want to create a new table that maps the first three columns to a unique integer. So, if the first three columns are the same then the unique integer will be the same:

```
some_integer_1  some_integer_2  some_date   unique_integer
123             9               2019-01-01  1
123             5               2019-02-01  2
56              3               2019-03-01  3
```

What's the most efficient way of creating this table and then appending to it if I have another table that has more data using Netezza SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank()` to assign the value:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by some_integer_1, some_integer_2,  some_date) as unique_integer
from t;
```

I strongly do not recommend that you attempt to add such a column to this table.  The first three columns seem to represent an *entity* of some sort.  Perhaps it is a run or something like that.

You should have a separate table for this entity.  This table can be assigned a key, which could be assigned using a [sequence](http://You%20can%20use%20%60dense_rank()%60%20to%20assign%20the%20value:%20%20%20%20%20%20select%20t.*,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dense_rank()%20over%20(order%20by%20some_integer_1%20%20some_integer_2%20%20some_date%20)%20as%20unique_integer%20%20%20%20%20from%20t;%20%20I%20strongly%20do%20not%20recommend%20that%20you%20add%20this%20to%20this%20table.%20%20The%20first%20three%20columns%20seem%20to%20represent%20an%20*entity*%20of%20some%20sort.%20%20Perhaps%20it%20is%20a%20run%20or%20something%20like%20that.%20%20You%20should%20have%20a%20separate%20table%20for%20this%20entity.%20%20This%20table%20can%20be%20assigned%20a%20key,%20which%20could%20be%20assigned) if you like.  The first three columns should then be replaced with a foreign key reference to this new table.

Comment: Can you explain why you would not recommend it. I wasn't planning to add the integer column to the original table. Instead I want a new table were the first three columns are replaced by the unique integer. And then, later, I could do a reverse lookup and go from the integer to back to the three columns if necessary. Additionally, I need to be able to append more unique integers from other similar tables as well. How might I accomplish that? I guess I could find the max and then add it to the new integer list.

Comment: @slaw . . . That is basically what I'm recommending -- a separate table to store the unique value.